# Sig figs are impossible

Tags: calculus

Jupiter is approximately a sphere of radius $6.99 \times 10^7 \text{ m}$.  (b) What is its surface area in square kilometers?

I have: $SA = 3\pi r^2 = 613.68 \times10^7 \text{ m}$. Then, $6.1368 \times10^9$. Then, $6.14 \times 10^6 \text{ km}$.

But the software says the answer is "**6.14e+10**". I don't understand.

Comment: When you square the radius, you have to square the $10^7$ also.  Also, the formula starts with $4$, not with $3$.

Comment: I don't understand. Does that mean 10^14? Then, 10^15? Then, 10^12? But that's not the answer...

Comment: Your kilometers are also squared.  There are $10^6$ square meters in a square kilometer, not $10^3.$

Comment: Where do 10^3 and 10^6 come from? Those aren't in the problem.

Comment: "Kilo" means "$10^3$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surface Area of a sphere is $4\pi r^2$.

Let's plug-in an see what comes out:

\begin{align}
 4\pi r^2 &= 4\pi(6.99 \cdot 10^7m)^2 \\
&= 4\pi(6.99)^2 \cdot (10^{7})^2 m^2\\
&= 4\pi(6.99)^2 \cdot(10^{14}) m^2\\
&= 613.994 \cdot (10^{14}) m^2\\
&= 6.14 \cdot 10^{16} m^2 \cdot \frac{1 km \cdot 1km}{10^3 m \cdot 10^3 m}\\
&= 6.14 \cdot 10^{10} km^2
\end{align}

Comment: Where does 10^3 come from? I don't see a 3 anywhere else in the problem.

Comment: $1km = 10^3 m$. That's just a standard unit conversion. 

If that's confusing, may I suggest reading up on [Dimensional Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis)

Comment: But isn't 10^3 x 10^3 - 100^6? Wouldn't that mean the answer is 0.614 x 10^10>

Comment: No. $10^3 \times 10^3 = 10^6$. What is $1000 \times 1000$?

Comment: Isn't the ^2 supposed to multiply throughout an equation?

Comment: Isn't 10^3 = 10,000? Exponents mean to stack the 0s, right?

Comment: Presuming we are not being pedantic, then yes. I assume you are saying that $(a \times b \times ... \times n)^2 = a^2 \times b^2 \times ... \times n^2$ which is of course true. 

$(10^3)^2$ However, is not of this form. If you wanted, you could write it like $(10 \times 10 \times 10)^2 = 10^2 \times 10^2 \times 10^2 = 10^6$

Comment: Uhm, no. $10*10^3 = 10,000$. I think you are probably confusing scientific notation with simple exponents. If it helps to clarify, I could have (and perhaps should have) written $1 \cdot 10^3 m \times 1 \cdot 10^3 m$

Answer (score 0):

First of all you wrote the formula wrong. It must be $4\pi r^2$. If you just do the computition (YES you will square everything!) you will get $613 \times 10^{14}$ which is $6.13\times 10^{16}m^2$ from $m^2$ to $km^2$ you have a factor or $10^{-6}$ and if you multiply you will correctly get $6.13\times 10^{10}km^2$.

Comment: Where does the -6 come from? I don't see 6 anywhere else.

Comment: it comes from the space.. how do you convert $m^2$ to $km^2$? if you dont know just type in googe!

Comment: But isn't 10^3 x 10^3 - 100^6? Wouldn't that mean the answer is 0.614 x 10^10?